# How is a pivot table created by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4, when working with many-to-many relationships as described in [the 4.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many), how can I actually get Laravel to create the pivot table for me?

Do I need to add something in my migrations for the two models that are involved? Do I need to manually create a migration for the pivot table? Or how does Laravel know to create the pivot table?

All I've done so far is add the `belongsToMany` information to the two respective models, i.e.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function roles()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
     }
 }
```

However, that does not trigger creation of the pivot table. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It appears as though the pivot table does need to be created manually (i.e. Laravel does not do this automatically). Here's how to do it:

1.) Create a new migration, using *singular* table names in *alphabetical* order (default):

```
php artisan make:migration create_alpha_beta_table --create --table=alpha_beta
```

2.) Inside the newly created migration, change the up function to:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('alpha_beta', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('alpha_id');
        $table->integer('beta_id');
    });
}
```

3.) Add the foreign key constraints, if desired.
(I haven't gotten to that bit, yet).

---

Now to seed, say, the alpha table, using keys from beta, you can do the following in your AlphaTableSeeder:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('alpha')->delete();

    Alpha::create( array( 
        'all'           =>  'all',
        'your'          =>  'your',
        'stuff'         =>  'stuff',
    ) )->beta()->attach( $idOfYourBeta );
}
```

Comment: If you are getting 'call to undefined method..." when your seed tries to run that {model}()->attach(/...  method, remember to created a model for both tablese, with a belongstomany in one of them. 

Eg, for this example: In models/Alpha.php you would include: 
  public function beta() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Beta');
  }

Comment: I think step 1 should be: ```php artisan migrate:make create_alpha_beta_table --create=alpha_beta```

Comment: is that first id field necessary?

Comment: for intermediate pivot tables, there should't be a primary key.

Comment: Drop the id, add foreign keys, and in most cases you also want a *unique* index covering both FKs.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan I agree, no AI primary key is needed. However, the touple [alpha_id,beta_id] should be the primary key, or at least indexed! Otherwise you query spped will slow downa  lot

Answer (score 44):

I use Jeffrey Way's [Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) or [Laravel-5-Generators-Extended](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended).

then you can just use this artisan command:

```
php artisan generate:pivot table_one table_two
```

Comment: This creates the foreign key constraints as well.

Comment: For Laravel-5-Generators-Extended, the command is `make:migration:pivot` and no longer `generate:pivot` (as it was in Laravel-4-Generators).

Answer (score 29):

To expand on Ben's answer (I tried to edit it but reviewers said it added too much):

To add the foreign key constraints, make sure if alpha id is unsigned, alpha_id is also unsigned in the pivot table. This migration would run after (2) in Ben's answer since it alters the table created then.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('alpha_beta', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('alpha_id')->references('id')->on('alpha');
        $table->foreign('beta_id')->references('id')->on('beta');
    });
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted on a 1.5 year old answer. Next time, comment for correction.

Comment: would you like to add an onDelete('cascade'); ?

Comment: `$table->foreignId('alpha_id')->constrained();` or `$table->foreignId('alpha_id')` and vice versa can be a better approach now.

Answer (score 12):

For Many to Many relationships you can create the Migration file of the Database manually like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateAccountTagTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('account_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // $table->timestamps(); // not required
            // $table->softDeletes(); // not required

            $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts');

            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('account_tag');
    }
}
```

**Note**: in case you have `timestamps` on the pivot table you must set `withTimestamps` on the relationship of both ends like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(\Mega\Modules\Account\Models\Tag::class)->withTimestamps();
```

.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(\Mega\Modules\Account\Models\Account::class)->withTimestamps();
```

Answer (score 11):

1. Create new migration:

```php
php artisan make:migration create_alpha_beta_table --create=alpha_beta
```

2. Inside the newly created migration:

```php
public function up() {
    Schema::create('alpha_beta', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('alpha_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('beta_id');
            // foreign keys
            $table->foreign('alpha_id')->references('id')->on('alphas');
            $table->foreign('beta_id')->references('id')->on('betas');
     });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

for the latest Laravel's versions:

```
composer require --dev laracasts/generators

php artisan make:migration:pivot table1 table2
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all the above answers

- There is no need to have an AI index for a pivot table. Its uniquely defined by its touple (key1,key2).
- The primary key should be the composition (key1,key2). The benefits are that the touples are unique and all queries are best optimized.

So here comes a real life example:

```
Schema::create('bill_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // unsigned is needed for foreign key
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('bill_id')->unsigned();

    $table->primary(['user_id', 'bill_id']);

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign(bill_id')
        ->references('id')->on('bills')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in the older version, you can use some generator or artisan to make pivots,
but in the newer version, this work is too easy.
**you must only make migration to do that like the below code.**

```
php artisan make:migration category_post --create=category_post
```

after run code
make migration with this params

```
 $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained('post');
 $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('category');
```

Answer (score 0):

following the latest laravel conventions, the `up` method should be

```php
public function up() {
        Schema::create('country_timezone', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
            $table->foreignId('timezone_id')->references('id')->on('timezones');
        });
    }
```

the simplest but modern way of writing pivot table migration, where the `Country` and `Timezone` are models with `many-to-many` relationship. And `id` and `timestamps` are not necessary to include but straightforward manner

Answer (score 0):

1-Create a migration for the pivot table by running the following command in your terminal:

`php artisan make:migration create_table_name_table`

2- In the migration file, create the pivot table with the columns that you need for your relationship.

`<?php Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->unsignedBigInteger('model1_id'); $table->unsignedBigInteger('model2_id'); // add any other columns that you need for your relationship $table->timestamps(); // set up composite key $table->primary(['model1_id', 'model2_id']); // set up foreign keys $table->foreign('model1_id')->references('id')->on('model1_table')->onDelete('cascade'); $table->foreign('model2_id')->references('id')->on('model2_table')->onDelete('cascade'); });`

3- In your models, set up the relationship between the two models and the pivot table.

`<?php class Model1 extends Model { public function model2s() { return $this->belongsToMany(Model2::class, 'table_name', 'model1_id', 'model2_id'); } } class Model2 extends Model { public function model1s() { return $this->belongsToMany(Model1::class, 'table_name', 'model2_id', 'model1_id'); } }`

4- To display the data in a pivot table format in your application, you can use the `withPivot()` method to retrieve the additional columns from the pivot table.

`<?php $model1 = Model1::find(1); foreach ($model1->model2s as $model2) { echo $model2->pivot->column_name; // include any other columns that you need from the pivot table }`