# How is a pivot table created by laravel 5

Tags: migration, pivot, laravel-5

I followed everything in http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many and I found the same problem in [How is a pivot table created by laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821822/how-is-a-pivot-table-created-by-laravel) after applying the solution I got the migration file and I've made my changes

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Card_User', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('Card_id');
          $table->integer('User_id');
          $table->integer('additional_var');
        });
    }
```

But when I try to `php artisan migrate:refresh` I always get

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                            
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.Card_User' d  
  oesn't exist (SQL: alter table `Card_User` add `id` int unsigned not null auto  
  _increment primary key, add `Card_id` int not null, add `User_id` int not null  
  , add `additional_var` int not null)                                    



  [PDOException]                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'waawia.Card_User' d  
  oesn't exist
```

> After folowwing some other webpages i tried to :
>
> - `php artisan migrate:install`
> - Delete all the database tables manually and refresh the migration
> - Restarted `php artisan serve` and now it's closed
> - Some other things ...
>
> But still have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are creating a table, change

`Schema::table('Card_User', function (Blueprint $table) {}`

to

`Schema::create('Card_User', function (Blueprint $table) {}`

`Schema::table()` is used to alter an existing table while `Schema::create()` does what it implies.

Comment: Thank you :') So much , I worked a lot and I didn't find it until now , I will choose your answer as the best one , just a minute ^_^ ありがとうぐざいます