# proper way to create ManyToMany relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I just started to work on a laravel project for my school assignment. I just have started it for about a week so my fundamental knowledge about laravel is not complete.

Today I bump into a problem with model many to many relationship in laravel. I create 2 model with migration A and B. In App\A.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class A extends Model
{
    //
    public function B(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\B');
    }
}
```

and in App\B.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class B extends Model
{
    //
    public function A(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\A');
    }
}
```

I think it should do the job. But when I use seeder to create dummy data, I got the error with is that table A_B is not created. I assume that I must create empty table A_B for 2 pivot columns which is annoying. Is there a better way, a proper way to create many to many relationship without manually create pivot table for them?

Comment: http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/ follow this it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not. There are shortcuts to doing it, like the way they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821822/how-is-a-pivot-table-created-by-laravel/15834061#15834061) but you will end up doing some manual work to create the table. You will end up using a migration anyway, but depending on the amount of control you want with the pivot, you might want to use a model for that. Using a model for a pivot table is not mandatory.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables

This could be what your migration would end up looking like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateABTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('A_B', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('a_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('b_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('a_id')->references('id')->on('a')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('A_B');
    }
}
```

But if you really wanted to, you could also create a custom table (with a custom name like ABRandomName) using a new model. Just look for the **Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models** header in the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: so, there is no way for laravel to create that pivot table automatically? And I have to create a miration or a pivot model?

Comment: I'm afraid not. There are shortcuts to doing it, like the way they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15834061/6903994), but you will end up doing some manual work to create the table. You will end up using a migration anyway, but depending on the amount of control you want with the pivot, you might want to use a model for that. Using a model for a pivot table is not mandatory.

Comment: Oh, that what I looking for, thank you for link me to that post

Comment: You're very welcome! Please don't forget to mark my answer as the solution if it helped  :)